# How to populate field in Gravity Forms from dropdown selection with a database query?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a Gravity Form in which I need to populate a field with information from a MySQL database table `wp_doordata` based on a match with a drop-down selection in the previous field.

#### Below an example

I select the value **"CRP10"** from the drop-down. I need to query the MySQL database table and select the field `door_data` that matches the selection of the value **"CRP10"** and populate the field `"door_data"` in the Gravity Form.

I can do this in PHP, but am not familiar with Wordpress/Gravity Forms as much and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Welcome to SO, I strongly suggest you to share more details regarding your question, this is not the correct way of asking a question here. In particular you need to include the code parts that are referring to the drop-down menu and the PHP part related to the population of the query. Furthermore for wordpress concepts is more correct to post this kind of questions here-> [wordpress.stackexchange.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com)

Comment: This is the best place to ask this question since in the WP Dev SE they see questions about plugins like Gravity Forms as off Topic and will close them.